# Wine not creating process/not working

Tags: debian, wine

So i used apt-get install wine to install wine on my debian 7.0 server.
It installed wine and wine64-bin.

Now whenever i try to start an .exe file it doesn't do anything.
Theres no error and no process being created. It simply doesn't do anything.

The command "wine" literally does nothing.

I tried running winecfg, but that just tells me command not found and i can't install it using apt-get -> package not found.

How do i properly install wine in debian 7.0 and configure it(terminal only)?

Comment: Did you install first wine64-bin package? Just installing that package (nothing else) and running the command wine the system will show you a nice message with the instructions about how to run wine in a 64 bits Debian machine. It tells you that you must enable multiarch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have followed these steps:

1. As root, install first wine64-bin package and nothing else (it just tells you how to enable multiarch, see second point)
2. As normal user, run command wine and you will see the next message:

   ** Debian / Wine: Multiarch Instructions **

   This is the wine64-bin helper package, which does not provide wine itself,
   but instead exists solely to provide the following information about
   enabling multiarch on your system in order to be able to install and run
   the 32-bit wine packages.

   The following commands should be issued as root or via sudo in order to
   enable multiarch (the last command installs 32-bit wine):

   # dpkg --add-architecture i386

   # apt-get update

   # apt-get install wine-bin:i386

   Be very careful as spaces matter above.  Note that this package
   (wine64-bin) will be removed in the process.  For more information on
   the multiarch conversion, see: http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO
3. As root, run the commands that the message is telling you and at the end you should finish having a wine installation running smoothly.